# Is there a way to add two numbers using a private constructor in C#

Tags: c#, constructor, private

I am trying add two numbers using private constructor but have failed till yet. Is there a way to add them?

```
class Program { 
     static void Main(string[] args) { 
         int add = Addition.add(); //Console.WriteLine() 
         Console.ReadKey(); 
     }
} 
public class Addition { 
     public static int num1, num2; 
     private Addition() { 
          Console.WriteLine("Enter two numbers"); 
          num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
          num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
    } 
    public static int add() { 
          return num1 + num2; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Plesae edit your question and add it formatted to the question itself. Also explain what is the problem with this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
public class Example {
    public int Result {get; private set;}
    private Example(int x, int y){
       Result = x + y;
    }
    public static Example Create(int x, int y){
         return new Example(x,y);
    }   
}
```